# Kotlin Multiplatform serve ktor as backend jvm module

Tags: kotlin, jvm, backend, ktor, kmm

I'm working on my multiplatform project and added ktor based backend module as part of it
as i wanted to share my common code with this backend module i've added it to dependencies

`implementation(project(":shared"))`

But there seems to be an issue with sharing code for jvm target(which ktor backend is)
I've found a workaround to have my project got this dependency resolved by marking this backend submodule as a multiplatform itself, but now as I build it and start to run I'm getting this error

**Error: Could not find or load main class com.owlsoft.backend.ServerKt**

My whole backend ktor build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}


kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
}

application {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    mainClassName.set("com.owlsoft.backend.ServerKt")
}


dependencies {
    implementation(Libs.Coroutines.core)

    implementation(Libs.KtorServer.core)
    implementation(Libs.KtorServer.netty)
    implementation(Libs.KtorServer.serialization)
    implementation(Libs.KtorServer.websockets)

    implementation(Libs.kotlinSerialization) // JVM dependency

    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    implementation(project(":shared"))
    testImplementation(Libs.KtorServer.test)
}

tasks.register("stage") {
    dependsOn("installDist")
}
```

I'm mostly trying to share some models and business logic
I've only made backend module with ktor in it multiplatform to fix issue with it's not being able to pick up shared module changes.

[image: So I have modules like this]

Comment: Ktor server is JVM-only. Could you please describe what code do you want to share across different platforms?

Comment: I've edited issue a little bit. So I'm trying to share a "shared" module which contains common models and some business logic
it works well for android app and ios but not so good for the "backend" module which is JVM based module and when I'm trying to do
```implement(project("shared")) in it it just doesn't see any models from my shared module

So I've tried to make backend multiplatform as well and it worked well as shared models now properly visible from inside of backend module
But I can not run the server in this backend module now . It fails with the error described above

Comment: I recommend using this sample project https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/main/fullstack-mpp as an example to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in the same scenario. I fixed this way:

1. Open your project in **Intellij IDEA**. Right click on the project name in the Project window
2. Select `Open Module Settings`
3. Check if `backend` module is inside your project, not as a separate module above. Remove the separate module if exists (code will remain the same).
4. Check if you have this folder structure in `backend`: `src - jvmMain - kotlin - Server.kt`

I think the root cause is that I added `backend` module with Android Studio and the project structure was broken somehow.